# How to create a temp file in java without the random number appended to the filename?

Tags: java, temporary-files

I need to create a temp file, so I tried this:

```
String[] TempFiles = {"c1234c10","c1234c11","c1234c12","c1234c13"};
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    try {
        String tempFile = TempFiles[i]; 
        File temp = File.createTempFile(tempFile, ".xls"); 
        System.out.println("Temp file : " + temp.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output is something like this:

```
 Temp file : C:\Users\MD1000\AppData\Local\Temp\c1234c108415816200650069233.xls
 Temp file : C:\Users\MD1000\AppData\Local\Temp\c1234c113748833645638701089.xls
 Temp file : C:\Users\MD1000\AppData\Local\Temp\c1234c126104766829220422260.xls
 Temp file : C:\Users\MD1000\AppData\Local\Temp\c1234c137493179265536640669.xls
```

Now, I don't want the extra numbers (long int) which is getting added to the file name. How can I achieve that? Thanks

Answer (score 48, accepted):

First, use the following snippet to get the system's temp directory:

```
String tDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
```

Then use the `tDir` variable in conjunction with your `tempFiles[]` array to create each file individually.

Comment: Will all of these manually created files automatically be deleted upon exit? (I assume so, but just to make sure, if someone could confirm).

Comment: Just to note that if you do this, you are not using File.createTempFile, but some other way of creating the file.

Answer (score 23):

Using [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava):

```
import com.google.common.io.Files;

...

File myTempFile = new File(Files.createTempDir(), "MySpecificName.png");
```

Comment: Thanks for saving my day!

Comment: You are a rockstar :)

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed.

Comment: It appears this is deprecated. Guava now recommends using `java.nio.file.Files` to create a tmp dir. See [here](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Files.html#createTempDir()) for more info.

Answer (score 20):

You can't if you use `File.createTempFile` to generate a temporary file name.  I looked at the java source for generating a temp file (for java 1.7, you didn't state your version so I just used mine):

```
private static class TempDirectory {
    private TempDirectory() { }

    // temporary directory location
    private static final File tmpdir = new File(fs.normalize(AccessController
        .doPrivileged(new GetPropertyAction("java.io.tmpdir"))));
    static File location() {
        return tmpdir;
    }

    // file name generation
    private static final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    static File generateFile(String prefix, String suffix, File dir) {
        long n = random.nextLong();
        if (n == Long.MIN_VALUE) {
            n = 0;      // corner case
        } else {
            n = Math.abs(n);
        }
        return new File(dir, prefix + Long.toString(n) + suffix);
    }
}
```

This is the code in the java JDK that generates the temp file name.  You can see that it generates a random number and inserts it into your file name between your prefix and suffix.  This is in "File.java" (in java.io).  I did not see any way to change that.

Answer (score 5):

If you want files with specific names created in the system-wide temporary directory, then expand the `%temp%` environment variable and create the file manually, nothing wrong with that.

Edit: Actually, use `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));` for that.

Answer (score 4):

Just putting up the option here:
If someone anyhow need to use createTempFile method, you can do create a temp file and rename it using Files.move option:

```
final Path path = Files.createTempFile(fileName, ".xls");
Files.move(path, path.resolveSibling(fileName));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a temp directory then store new files in it. This way all of the new files you add won't have a random extension to it. When you're done all you have to do is delete the temp directory you added.

```
public static File createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix) {       
    File parent = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));   

    File temp = new File(parent, prefix + suffix);

    if (temp.exists()) {
        temp.delete();
    }

    try {
        temp.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return temp;
}


public static File createTempDirectory(String fileName) {       
    File parent = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));   

    File temp = new File(parent, fileName);

    if (temp.exists()) {
        temp.delete();
    }

    temp.mkdir();

    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom names can be saved as follows

```
File temp=new File(tempFile, ".xls");
if (!temp.exists()) {
    temp.createNewFile();
}
```

Comment: Downvote. The call to `temp.exists()` introduces a race condition that `temp.createNewFile()` was specifically designed to avoid. Just check the return value of `temp.createNewFile()`. Read the specification of `createNewFile()`. The important word is *atomic*. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29

Answer (score 0):

In my case with create *.img file in Android app:

Instead:

```
private File createImageFileWithRandomSufix() throws IOException {
    String photoName = "photo_1";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(photoName, ".jpg", storageDir);
    return image;
}
```

Use this:

```
private File createImageFileWithoutRandomSufix() throws IOException {
    String photoName = "photo_1";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = new File(storageDir + "/" + photoName + ".jpg");
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static File createTempDirectory(String dirName) {
        File baseDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
        File tempDir = new File(baseDir, dirName);
        if (tempDir.mkdir()) {
          return tempDir;
        }
        return null;
}
```

Comment: Adding some explanation for the code would be helpful for the OP.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.