# How to use temp file from which i get inputStream

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey-2.0

i am trying to upload a file to the web using rest web service. i created a flow which accept a file in the form as:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(

        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetails,
        @FormDataParam("location") String uploadedFileLoc   ) {
        .
        .
}
```

Here at the end of method, i need to return the file which client uploaded and in the next method that file is converted into the byte array.
Basically i am getting the file in a "InputStream" format. Does there is any way that i could get as an file itself ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'a file itself' ? What is exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: the flow is designed in mule studio. the component "File to Byte Array Transformer" required file to transform, for which we need to send the file through the above class - by accepting through the client.

Comment: I think that if you want to return a File object to this other "File to Byte Array Transformer" you would have to write the InputStream into a File and then send the File.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the suggestion. The main thing i need to do is converting the file to byte array. Since i am getting the InputStream, i could pass this as the return to the next flow rather than waiting for the file itself.
In the next flow rather than using a "file to byte array" transformer, just use "Object to byte array" transformer. Finally it works.

Comment: `@raviKumar` 
See my answer this may help you !

Answer (score 2):

`@Ravi Kumar`

You can use

```
public Response uploadFileSimple(@FormDataParam("file") File file, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition formData)
```

It return you a File object directly, But jersey it self create File object in temp for you, So you can say there is two temp file with same size.

```
First MIMExxxxx.tmp from where you get you input steam

Second re234xxxx  from which you get this file object
```

`NOTE :` Before calling your resource method jersey take time to create this two file(as per file size).

And if you want to use directly `MIMExx.tmp` file, Then i don't think there is straightforward way you may use `JAVA REFLECTION` to get temp file path and use.

Using Java Reflection :

```
@Path("/upload/{parentfolderid}")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFileWithPart(FormDataMultiPart form)
    {

        try
        {
            FormDataBodyPart filePart = form.getField("upload");
            BodyPartEntity bodyPart = (BodyPartEntity) filePart.getEntity();

            MIMEPart mimePart = (MIMEPart) readFieldValue("mimePart", bodyPart);
            Object dataHead = readFieldValue("dataHead", mimePart);
            Object dataFile = readFieldValue("dataFile", dataHead);
            File tempFile = null;
            if (dataFile != null)
            {
                Object weakDataFile = readFieldValue("weak", dataFile);
                tempFile = (File) readFieldValue("file", weakDataFile);
            }
            else
            {
                tempFile = filePart.getValueAs(File.class);
            }

    // Here is your *tempFile*, Do what ever you want with it
}

private static Object readFieldValue(String fieldName, Object o) throws Exception
{
    Field field = o.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    return field.get(o);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

File is a file, Stream is a stream.

If you need a file from a stream you need to create the file and write the stream into the file.

You can use temp folder for this:
[How to create a temp file in java without the random number appended to the filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594886/how-to-create-a-temp-file-in-java-without-the-random-number-appended-to-the-file)

and create a temp file there.

**UPD**

For your needs, File.createTempFile() should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Jersey REST API for file upload. For example,

```
@Path("/upload")
public class FileUploadService{
      @POST

@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

      String location = "/" + fileDetail.getFileName();

    // save it
    writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, location);

    String output = "File uploaded to : " + location;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

      }

}
```

And to save the file you have this method:

```
private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
    String location) {

    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                location));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(location));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Hope it helps!