# report is downloaded in a different name while using JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm using this code to generate a pdf file from a report "jrxml" but the pdf file is generated with numbers in the name. for example

joelle8172361278631763.pdf can you help me fix this problem

```
public String showReport () throws JRException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File pdf = File.createTempFile("joelle", ".pdf");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pdf) ;          
        initConnection();
        String reportName = "C:\\folder\\Outgoings.jrxml";

        JasperDesign jasperDesign = null;
        try {
            jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load( reportName);
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, conn);

            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, out);
            try {
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (JRException e) {
                    System.out.println("catch2");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
return null ; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not the *JasperReports* framework itself that causes the name to change but rather the standard SDK call `File.createTempFile("joelle", ".pdf");` which resorts to `File.generateFile` that appends a random number to the filename to ensure its uniqueness:

```
private static File generateFile(String prefix, String suffix, File dir)
        throws IOException
    {
        long n = LazyInitialization.random.nextLong();
        if (n == Long.MIN_VALUE) {
            n = 0;      // corner case
        } else {
            n = Math.abs(n);
        }
        return new File(dir, prefix + Long.toString(n) + suffix);
    }
```

Please refer to this topic on how to create temp files without having their names modified here: [How to create a temp file in java without the random number appended to the filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594886/how-to-create-a-temp-file-in-java-without-the-random-number-appended-to-the-file?rq=1)

Comment: I have read it but I didn't really understand ... What to do with tDir next ?

Comment: It is actually up to you how would you like to handle the creation of those temporary files. For instance you could start off by trying to determine if a given file already exists by invoking `File.exists` method and then deleting it if necessary. Also you can think of utilizing `File.deleteOnExit()` to have it automatically discarded when the process terminates.