# Android: Uri filename confusion

Tags: android, uri

I'm simply trying to pass uri from one activity to another. And while doing that I noticed that I received a no file found exception and I could see that the end filenames were not the same by printing them out. (Just the `path` string and `uri.getEncodedPath()`)

So I tried sending the string and reconstructing the uri as follows:

```
Log.e("debug_path_string", data.getExtras().getString(CONSTANT));

# try { Uri photoUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(data.getExtras().getString(CONSTANT))); }
try { Uri photoUri = Uri.parse(data.getExtras().getString(CONSTANT)); }
catch (Exception e) { Log.e("IO", e.getMessage()); }

Log.d("debug", photoUri.getEncodedPath());
pageListAdapter.append(photoUri);
```

and the logs

```
12-26 04:18:04.172 4425-4425/com.example.myawesomeapp E/debug_path_string: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myawesomeapp/files/Pictures/JPEG_20171226_041803672615875.jpg
12-26 04:18:04.172 4425-4425/com.example.myawesomeapp D/debug: /document_images/JPEG_20171226_041746-1723016833.jpg
12-26 04:18:04.225 4425-4425/com.example.myawesomeapp W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored
12-26 04:18:04.400 4425-4425/com.example.myawesomeapp W/Glide: Load failed for content://com.example.myawesomeapp.fileprovider/document_images/JPEG_20171226_041746-1723016833.jpg
```

Are

```
file://storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myawesomeapp/files/Pictures/JPEG_20171226_041803672615875.jpg
content://com.example.myawesomeapp.fileprovider/document_images/JPEG_20171226_041746-1723016833.jpg

# provided 
# com.example.myawesomeapp.fileprovider/document_images resolves path
# storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myawesomeapp/files/Pictures
```

equivalent?

Obviously the load failed because it couldn't find such a file. (I checked the path and a file with filename as in the string path exists).

Can someone explain me why `Uri.parse()` or `Uri.fromFile(new file(path))` tries to create a filename different from that of the original?

Why does Android seem to dislike `JPEG_20171226_041803672615875` but `JPEG_20171226_041746-1723016833` and on what basis does it change?

---

**Note:** I did try sending `Uri` directly using `data.putExtra()` and `data.getParcelableExtra()`. They are giving the same results as if I sent the string and constructed an Uri from that.

---

**UPDATE:** I'm using `File.createTempFile()` which appends a random number at the end. Even it FilesProvider is generating its own reference, it still shouldn't t touch he original filename which is `JPG_date_time`.

While observing what it changed, I just noticed this strange thing!

```
|......16.......||.......rest......|

JPEG_20171226_041803672615875.jpg
JPEG_20171226_041746-1723016833.jpg

# Running one more example
JPEG_20171226_121309-2003514507.jpg
JPEG_20171226_121239-882490989.jpg

|......16.......||.......rest......|
```

It is preserving the first 16 characters...!!! This makes me feel it's definitely got something to do with the length.

Comment: I suggest you to refer https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html

Comment: Have a look at photoUri.toString().

Comment: I'm surprised why this 16 char stuff isn't mentioned in the docs even as a warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It was strangely the length that was causing the problem.**

Keeping the file name under 16 characters solves the problem. Yes, works just like that without requiring any changes. Notice if you're using `File.createTempFile()` it will add 5 or more characters *(In my case it was 9)* as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9595010/3125070).

Although this solves the problem for now, this leads to another question: *What if I wanted 16+ characters?*

Answer (score -3):

If you want to pass Uri form one activity to another activity, so please use intent like this:

```
Uri Uri1=new Uri();
class A:
Intent intent=new Intent(A.this,B.class)
intent.set Data(Uri1);
start Activity(intent);
Class B
Intent intent=getIntent();
Uri uri=intent.getData();
```