# Create Temp File with specific name

Tags: java, android

I need to create Temp `File` with specific name without Random Number and if there are no solutions, How can I rename the generate file in `Internal storage`

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

    //storageDir.mkdirs();
    String imageFileName = Integer.toString(ImgCount)+"temp";
    File storageDir1= getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES+ImgDir);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir1     /* directory */
    );

    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

the create file is saved like this 
`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/....../**1temp1004505332.jpg**`

Comment: Well, you just change imageFileName to what you want, or pass in a paramater to it?

Comment: already I passed the needed file name to File.createTempFile  ,  but it add random number after the input file name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a temp file in java without the random number appended to the filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594886/how-to-create-a-temp-file-in-java-without-the-random-number-appended-to-the-file)

Answer (score 4):

You can not do this with `File.createTempFile()`, [Below is from documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File))

> File createTempFile (String
>   prefix, 
>                   String suffix, 
>                   File directory) Creates a new empty file in the specified directory, using the given prefix and suffix strings to
>   generate its name. If this method returns successfully then it is
>   guaranteed that:
>
> The file denoted by the returned abstract pathname did not exist
>   before this method was invoked, and Neither this method nor any of its
>   variants will return the same abstract pathname again in the current
>   invocation of the virtual machine.

However you can use `File(String pathname)` for creating a file with specified name and path, not to forget you will need [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) if you writing to external storage

> Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string
>   into an abstract pathname.

Answer (score 1):

In your case use this if you want to store file with specific name:

```
File image = new File(
        storageDir1 , 
        imageFileName + 
        ".jpg"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### use /tmp/{fileName}

```
File tempFile = new File(
    "/tmp/",
    fileName
);
```